# В чем разница между этими загрузками данных?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Помогите разобраться в запросе EF, не могу понять, чем они отличаются и как будут транслируются в SQL запросы указанные в Program(е)

Есть следующая тестовая модель

```
class TestModel
{
    public ICollection<Company> Company { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    // Еще некоторые поля
}

class Company
{ /*Некий код*/ }

class User
{ /*Некий код*/ }
```

```
DbSet<TestModel> testModel { get; set; }
```

Program:

```
var request = contextBD.testModel
    .Include(a => a.Company)
    .Include(a => a.User)
  
var result = request.ToArray();

//AND

var request = contextBD.testModel;
request.Select(a => a.Company).Load();
request.Select(a => a.User).Load();

var result = request.ToArray();
```

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/). См. энергичную и явную загрузку.

Comment: [Overview of Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/). См. Simple logging.